# jquery $(document).ready firing twice

Tags: jquery, events, document, document-ready

I'm using JQuery 1.9.   when i fire off this ajax function in the document ready, it is firing  the function twice.

```
function CandyLoad() {
jInput.Category = "Candy";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Pages/SnackShop/wsSnackShop.aspx/_LoadCategory",
    data: "{'jInput':" + JSON.stringify(jInput) + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // Show the error
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        aryCandy = data.d;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                           $('#Candy').append('<tr><td>' + data.d[i].Name + '</td></tr>')
        }

    }
})
```

};

I've commented out everything in my javascript file other then the jInput class that i've created.   There is no other javascript firing on the page.  I setup a breakpoint on the CandyLoad function and it's getting hit twice.  I've verified that i am not calling it anywhere else (espeically now since everything is commented out).  Am i doing something wrong in the success portion of the ajax call that if would fire again.

Any help would be great... as i have not been able to find an answer in my search.. 
thanks
shannon

edit ---

I figured out the issue.. I was calling the javascript file twice.. had something buried in a user control.  Many thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Can you show how you are invoking this function? (also take a look to make sure it doesn't get fired somewhere else - maybe a separate file that is included)

Comment: If document.ready is executing twice, you are executing it twice yourself. jQuery does not and cannot trigger it twice.

Comment: I was looking in chrome dev tools to see if there were any other files loading.. didn't see any.. but now that you mention it, i'm using a user control in my asp.net that has a javascript file in it.. i'll start looking there..  thanks.. but i may be back :)

Comment: check the url you are sending the request to. Sometimes adding a forward slash at the end helps.
try: `"/Pages/SnackShop/wsSnackShop.aspx/_LoadCategory/"`